# queryParams are not reflected in URL while using navigateByUrl

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my component, when I try

```
this.router.navigate([`/courses/`, course.id], {queryParams:{description: course.description}});
```

After navigation, URL has `description` query parameter.

But, when I try this one,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/courses/${course.id}`, {queryParams:{description: course.description}});
```

URL does not have `description` query parameter inside it.

Do I need to make changes to reflect my query parameter inside the URL while using `navigateByUrl`? (But, [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) says that `NavigationExtras` object is same for both `navigate` and `navigateByUrl`.)

Comment: please check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems query params are ignored by `navigateByUrl` method and documentation is not clear enough. Take a look at those links for more info: [link 1](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798) [link 2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22668).

As a workaround you can try this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(
  this.router.createUrlTree(
    ['some/route'], {queryParams: myParamObject}
  );
);
```